# How to disable or remove the default HighChart loading message?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Inside my Chart config I'm currently trying this which is not working:

```
loading: {
    // labelStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    style: { opacity: 0, display: 'none' },
    hideDuration: 0
},
```

I want to avoid showing the user the lame `loading...` that comes up when you first login or refresh our app. We have our own custom animation for when actions happen to the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
 chart.hideLoading();
 chart.showLoading('sample message...');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bxmvC/120/)**